# How to insert javascript function in css link tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, scriptlet

How can we call a javascript function inside some css link tag ?

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://<%=getServerIP()%>/path/to/cssFiles/file1.css" type="text/css">
```

As we can see that, this scriplet works just fine. It calls scriptlet function. Grabs the IP. Access the css file.

I need to do the same thing with javascript function.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://'getServerIP()'/path/to/cssFiles/file1.css" type="text/css">
```

Why not the second way is not working ? Any work around ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no similar syntax in javascript for dropping variables into the html like you can in PHP.  In order to dynamically load a CSS file in javascript, you would need to create a link element and append it to the head.  Something like this:

```
function loadCssFile(filename){
  var linkElement=document.createElement("link");
  linkElement.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  linkElement.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  linkElement.setAttribute("href", filename);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(linkElement);
}

var url = 'https://'+getServerIP()+'/path/to/cssFiles/file1.css';
loadCssFile(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I will try out that for sure.
But still one more confusion.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript:hello()" type="text/css">

<a href="javascript:hello()">click me</a>

Second statement is working fine. why not first statement ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript:hello()" type="text/css">
<script>
function hello()
{
alert('hi');
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:hello()">click me</a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: That's just not how link elements work.  You cannot include javascript in a link element's href attribute like you can with an anchor (a) element

Comment: I would like to !! but not enough reputation. I'm newbie :)